# Find and replace tags and its contents in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that contains BBcode and I managed to remove all the formatting with this code:

```
$plain_text = strip_tags(str_replace(array('[',']'), array('<','>'), $message));
```

But I have one piece of code that I want to remove its contents.
This code:

```
[ATTACH=full]4281[/ATTACH]
```

The number '4281' will always be different, so how can I remove it?

I tried:

```
preg_replace("/[ATTACH=full](.*)[\/ATTACH]/eis", '', $message);
```

but that doesn't work. I'm guessing it's something to do with the "attach=full" part and the equal sign.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: The equal sign does not have any special meaning; but the square brackets do (character class) – so you need to escape those. And remove the `e` modifier – apart from being deprecated and therefor generating a warning, it has no useful purpose here anyway.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, it always depends on what do you want to achieve. In case performance no one can beat regular expressions

Comment: @Ironank try https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode with ContentHandler as default, it will discard all BBCode tags and leave contents intact. If you want to remove all BBCodes completely, use NullHandler. I'd be happy to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk thanks, I will definitely get back to you if I have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
preg_replace("/\[ATTACH=full\].*\[\/ATTACH\]/", '', $message);
```

As Cbroe said, you needed to scape the '[' and ']' characters.

**UPDATE:** Added slash '/' at beginning and end of the regex.

Comment: You're right, I escaped those characters but still, I get this error: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Hi @Ironank, I updated the solution with a slash '/', as it was needed to solve the 'delimiter' problem. I tested on a simple php script. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, just tired that and no more error. However, for some reason it's not removing what's inside the tags. I tried .* and also (.*) but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Woops, scratch that, my fault. Your code works great, thanks! @Arcangel2p